# Jews wearing a hat, jacket or cap during davening

Tags: halacha, tefilla, sources-mekorot, clothing

Some Jews wear a *hat, cap* or *jacket* during davening. However, is there any *halacha* that says a Jew must wear and a *hat* and *jacket* during davening?

Comment: Offhand, some items in your question appear superfluous, and I'm a bit confused on which dress aspects you really want to know about. You list, at the beginning several combos, but your questions only focus on the hat + jacket combo. Is that the ONLY combo you're interested in, or do you want to know about any others including, perhaps, those you didn't mention. E.g., my sons' yeshiva required a black hat (no brim width or crown height specified, and it could even be crumpled!) and button-down shirt (any color & even ugly checked shirts!) but no jacket. There are "endless" combos, here!

Comment: _Baer Hetev_ 183:11 says so about _birchas hamazon_, but that's not what you asked about (and I don't know whether "we" rule like the _Baer Hetev_ about that).

Comment: Since I cannot comment yet I will broaden the question.
Is it right to wear a jacket while wearing tefillin half on and half off.
That is not the way one stands before a king.